# JOptionPane#showMessageDialog causes an application freeze

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I need to show information message to the user and I use the following code for this purpose:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

but program loops or what I don't know on this string of code. No matter what is insead of "message" I still got my app frozen. I didn't done anything about this string of code but changed IDE to eclipse and imports might have changed. I checked it and see the only import in my class for Joption: `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;`.

What may be wrong or how to check what is wrong?

Comment: Frozen even after closing the dialog?

Comment: @Arvind it didn't even open. The reason found: dialogs can't be opened when the app started from ide in debug mode

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "message", "result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: I don't see any differences